# How can I compare across vectors by index and return index sets that have the same values?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Given a set of binary vectors S, what is the most efficient way to compare all elements in every vector in S, and return all sets of indices that have the same value across all vectors?

for example:

[image]

Here the vectors are displayed horizontally, and each element is labelled x1, x2, x3, etc. The algorithm should return the sets {x1, x8} and {x7, x9} (ignore x4 and x6 in the image, that is related to another problem).

Here is my (very hacky) solution so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    // initialise test vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vecs;
    vecs.push_back(std::vector<int>{0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1});
    vecs.push_back(std::vector<int>{1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1});
    vecs.push_back(std::vector<int>{1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0});
    
    // vector to keep track if index already in a group
    std::vector<int> in_group (vecs[0].size(), 0);
    
    // output vector
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > output;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vecs[0].size(); ++i){
        // if already in group, skip current index
        if (in_group[i]) continue;
        else in_group[i] = 1;
        
        // vector to store values in current group
        std::vector<int> curr_group {i};
        
        for (int j = i+1; j < vecs[0].size();++j){
            bool match = true;
            // if already in a group, continue
            if (in_group[j]) continue;
            for (int s = 0; s < vecs.size(); ++s){
                if (vecs[s][i] != vecs[s][j]){
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if loop completed without breaking, match found
            if (match){
                curr_group.push_back(j);
                in_group[j] = 1;
            }
            
        }
        // put current group in output vector
        output.push_back(curr_group);
    }
    
    // display output
    for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < output[i].size(); ++j){
            std::cout << "x" << output[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It basically just iterates over each index and compares each other index on each of the vectors, and if it gets to the bottom without a mismatch, it adds it to the current group. If no match is found, the group is added with only the single index (this is a desired function). The output to this function is:

```
x0 x7 
x1 
x2 
x3 
x4 
x5 
x6 x8
```

Which is correct (if you translate the value of each index, +1), so it works. I am just wondering if there is a better/faster way to do this, maybe using a fancy data structure or something? The vectors that I am comparing are very large (up to a million values per vector), and I am comparing across many vectors (up to 1000+), so efficiency is important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to improve working code better ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: how many columns maximum?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {

    // initialise test vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vecs;
    vecs.push_back(std::vector<int>{0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1});
    vecs.push_back(std::vector<int>{1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1});
    vecs.push_back(std::vector<int>{1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0});

    std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::vector<int>> groups;

    for (int i = 0; i < vecs[0].size(); ++i){
        unsigned key = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < vecs.size(); ++j) {
            key += vecs[j][i] << j;
        }
        groups[key].push_back(i);
    }


    // display output
    for (const auto& group : groups) {
        for (auto index : group.second) {
            std::cout << "x" << index << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Going in the right direction, but an unsigned integer is completely insufficient. Needs at least to use a custom big int type to accommodate the full number of rows.

Comment: @Ext3h The full number of rows is three, as far as I can tell; nothing in the text of the question appears to suggest otherwise. `unsigned` would handle that just fine. But if you need something that can handle arbitrarily large sets, use `vector<bool>` for `key`; there's even a built-in `hash` implementation for it.

Comment: something like `boost::dynamic_bitset` is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a set of vectors that record the set of indices having a given sequence. Each stage you split each vector depending the next binary value, eliminating any vectors that reduce to size 1.

```
stage 1:
split { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }
<0> -> { 1,2,5,6,8 }
<1> -> { 3,4,7,9 }
stage 2:
split { 1,2,5,6,8 }
<0> -> { 2,6 }
<1> -> { 1,5,8 }
split { 3,4,7,9 }
<0> -> { 3 }  <-- eliminate as size is 1
<1> -> { 4,7,9 }
stage 3:
split { 2,6 } 
<0> -> { 6 }   <-- eliminate as size is 1
<1> -> { 2 }   <-- eliminate as size is 1
split { 1,5,8 }
<0> -> { 5 }   <-- eliminate as size is 1
<1> -> { 1,8 }
split { 4,7,9 }
<0> -> { 7,9 }
<1> -> { 4 }  <-- eliminate as size is 1
```

Note that you don't need to record the sequence, just split the vectors from the previous stage based on the values in the current binary vector. The worst case is you examine each element of the arrays once therefore the complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, transform each column into an object. You need to be able to perform a comparison on each two objects. Any "big integer" implementation should suffice.

With these, build a vector of pairs, consisting of the column index and the big int.

Sort this vector by the big integer, and now all matching columns are subsequent in the vector.

Finally iterate once to find each group of identical columns and you are done.

Runtime complexity of this algorithm is just O(n log n), which is magnitudes faster than your current O(n^3) implementation.